# Нахождение палиндромов в матрице

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, матрицы

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  double a[100][100];
  int n;
  cout << "n: ";
  cin >> n;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      cin >> a[i][j];
    }
  }
  cout << "massive: " << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      cout << a[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      if (a[i][j] == a[j][n - 1 - i]) {
        cout << "Palindrom";
      } else {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

В последнем цикле не могу организовать поиск в каждой строке. Либо ищет только в 1, либо все что не нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно найти **строки** в матрице, которые являются палиндромами, то вот пример кода с комментариями:

```
bool isPalindrome = true;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    //Изначально скажем что i-ая строка это палиндром
    isPalindrome = true;
    //Проверим левую и правую часть строки на совпадения
    //и если хотя бы одно не совпадение, то сразу говорим
    //что строка не является палиндромом
    for (int j = 0; j < n / 2 && isPalindrome; j++)
        if(a[i][j] != a[i][n - 1 - j])
            isPalindrome = false;
    if (isPalindrome)
        cout << "Строка с индексом " << i << " является палиндромом!" << endl;
    else cout << "Строка с индексом " << i << " не является палиндромом!" << endl;
}
```